# Displaying all fields in rails ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I've followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry for creating forums

In messages_helper.rb

```
def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
        render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

In index.html.erb

```
<%= nested_messages @messages.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
```

The nested_messages method is used to display only messages and sub messages
If I want to display images or any other fields, How can I display?

Comment: What's in the template?

Comment: @DaveNewton I can't get you?

Comment: You're asking how to display other fields. I'm saying it's in the template.

Comment: In template it shows for displaying messages and sub messages..how can i display other fields

Comment: I got it..we need to use content_tag(:div, message.id) for displaying id field